# Excel 2007 query

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

How do I write formula in Excel to first check four cells in a row to see if one of them contains a number and then perform a different calculation depending on which cell has a number and then display the result of the calculation.

E.g., it needs to check for a number in cells B6, C6, D6 and E6. 
There will be only one number in one of these cells. 
Depending on which cell has the number the calculations will be as follows:

- B6 × 52
- C6 × 12
- D6 × 4
- E6 × 8

I have tried nested `IF` statements but no luck.

Comment: This doesn’t sound very hard.  What did you try? … … … … … … … … … … Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Comment: I was using nested IF statements but it would only work on the first cell it checked and calculate an answer if it found a number. Am not sure the IF function is the way to go

Answer (score 2):

If only one of the cells will have a number
and the others will be blank, you can use:

```
=B6*52 + C6*12 + D6*4 + E6*8
```

Blank cells will be treated as zero, so only the cell with a number will have a non-zero result.  No need for nested IFs.

Comment: Hey Fixer1234 ......,thank you how brilliantantly simple.

Comment: @Johnny, glad to help.  If this answered your question, please consider [accepting the answer](https://superuser.com/help/accepted-answer) by clicking the ✓ button.  :-)